# how to Identify Killer wireless N 1202 on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I bought this Dell ultrabook (XPS 13) with Ubuntu and I know Dell is known for messing up orders. (plus I had some problems on the Wifi, that's why I've been investigating deeper).

The wifi card on it is supposed to be a `Killer wireless N 1202` but a a simple `sudo lshw -C network` gives me

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: <shows the serial number>
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.3.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:d0400000-d047ffff memory:bfa00000-bfa0ffff
```

and according to [this wiki entry](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Bigfoot_Networks_Killer_Wireless-N_1202) the killer uses the same chipset than the budget AR9462.

So the question, how do I reliably identify that they are giving me the correct stuff without having to crack open this tiny ultrabook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It determines the name from the PCI ID the device is showing, looking it up in `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids`. In this case `168c:0034` (check with `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 net`) and that's translating out as an Atheros chipset.

It isn't uncommon for wireless brands to use chipsets they didn't manufacture. I have no problem believing you have the Killer Wireless-N in your laptop, it's just not what you thought it was before you bought it.

This should probably also serve as a lesson about being up-sold "professional" and "gaming" level tat.

---

The important thing here is removing the conflation between product and chipset.

Ubuntu talks to the chipset so that's really all it knows about. All we can do here is confirm that you're running a device that contains a AR9462 chip.

As you've already shown, the Killer Wireless N 1202 contains a AR9462. It seems logical that they are one and the same. If you want to confirm that the Killer Wireless N 1202 contains an AR9462, you'll either have to ask Killer, or rip one open. the chipset. Talk to Killer if you need a second opinion but [images like this](http://i.ebayimg.com/t/Bigfoot-Killer-Wireless-N-1202-2x2-Half-Mini-PCIe-with-Bluetooth-4-0-/00/s/MzgxWDQyNw==/%24%28KGrHqN,!oUE+CBv5mFMBQDerdiqcQ~~60_35.JPG) suggest that this is the case.

If you need to confirm that this is actually a Killer Wireless N 1202 and not just any old AR9462-bearing device, you're going to have to open it up (or trust the retailer).

Comment: Hi. I guess it's a good enough answer, although not really answering the specific question (how to find it out). The original issue is not even about being up-sold, but on the website says it's an Intel Centrino, I didn't notice on the receipt said is a Killer N and the pre-installed Ubuntu the wifi was simply not working. Which made me start digging deeper until the moment I installed from ubuntu.com and everything worked fine. So it's an issue more about break of trust then up-sold with small "gaming details". At least I can demand to be what's exactly on the receipt. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I've added a bit more to my answer. I don't think you've been missold anything but you won't know for sure unless you open it up. And even then it could be counterfeit (that's an increasingly large problem with some components).

Answer (score 0):

This package provides Qualcomm Killer [Wireless-N1202](http://www.software-driver.com/dell/dell-alienware-14-qualcomm-killer-wireless-n1202-driver-for-windows-78-64bit/) Driver and is supported on Alienware Notebook Alienware 14, Alienware 17 & Alienware 18 running the following Windows Operating

Comment: This packages seems to be only available for Windows.